# context-aware inserting closing parentheses character

Tags: pairing

Most of auto pair packages provides that automatic insertion of closing parentheses (one of `)`, `}`, `]`.) if you type a opening parenthese.

However, what I want is when I type a closing pair, I want Emacs want to replace the closing character based on the context.  For example (`|` is the point):

```
([([|
```

No matter which closing character (like one of `)`, `]`, or `}`) I typed, I want Emacs smartly insert `]`, `)`, `]`, and `)` respectively.

Is there any minor mode to do that?
(FYI, I need such a feature while I'm editing Scheme or Clojure source files)

Thanks.

---

After experimenting `syntactic-close` (provided by [Manuel Uberti](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5514/manuel-uberti)), I wanted to bind it to all of `)`, `]`, `}`, and `>`.

One minor update. It looks like that `syntactic-close` will not insert closing character if there is no matching opening one. And the set of closing characters varies depending on the major-mode. What I want it is to insert matching closing character if it found, and if not, I want it to insert the character that I typed.  So I came up with the small wrapper like this:

```
(defun syntactic-close-or-self-insert (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (unless (call-interactively 'syntactic-close)
    (call-interactively 'self-insert-command nil
                        [(listify-key-sequence (this-command-keys))])))

(let ((mode-maps (list
                  lisp-mode-shared-map
                  racket-mode
                  geiser-repl-mode-map
                  clojure-mode-map)))
  (dolist (map mode-maps)
    (define-key map [(?\))] 'syntactic-close-or-self-insert)
    (define-key map [(?\])] 'syntactic-close-or-self-insert)
    (define-key map [(?\})] 'syntactic-close-or-self-insert)
    (define-key map [(?\>)] 'syntactic-close-or-self-insert)))
```

It may not be optimal, but it does serve my purpose.   Thanks Manuel, and if you have any more advice, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [syntactic-close](https://github.com/emacs-berlin/syntactic-close).

From the package README:

> Insert closing delimiter char(s), i.e. parenthesis, bracket(s),
>   brace(s) or whatever is needed.
>
> That way closing may be done by just one convenient key.

I needed something similar to your requirement a while ago.

FWIW, I wrote about this package and how I configured it [here](https://manuel-uberti.github.io/emacs/2017/09/17/syntactic-close/):

```el
(use-package syntactic-close            ; Automatically insert closing delimiter
  :ensure t
  :bind ("C-c x c" . syntactic-close))
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer, if it solved your problem.